# Stop at first lookahead match with two options

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-look-ahead

I'm trying to generate a RegEx that grabs all the content in between "**<**" and "**>**" and stops if it finds a "**|**". For example:

This is the link <`stackoverlflow.com`> 
This is the link <`https://stackoverlflow.com`>
This is the link <`stackoverlflow.com` | Click here>
This is the link <`https://stackoverlflow.com` | Click here>

I tried with something like this but it doesn't work: `((?!<)[^\s]+((?=>)|(?=\|)))` 
Can you help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=<)[^<>\s|]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fjkYm5/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=<)` - a location immediately preceded with `<`
- `[^<>\s|]+` - 1 or more chars other than `<`, `>`, whitespace and `|`.